# Useability of the user registration workflow

Tags: 7, ajax, users

When you want to create an account on a drupal7 page, you have to click very often to create the account finaly.

1. Go on user/register
2. Click on one time login link
3. Open the one time login page and click an login
4. Change password
5. Now your done

Are there any approaches to modify the registration process without loosing the email verification? There so many Websites doing it better. Is there a Drupal way?

Comment: _There so many Websites doing it better_ So ...pick one you like and implement it, what's the problem exactly?

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to make the registration more comfortable for users. Its no option to change the Framework. I love Drupal

Comment: What does "more comfortable for users" mean though? Only you know what you mean by that

Comment: Have you ever registerd on tumblr.com? There are three fields, email, password and username. You can fill the fields click on next, agree the terms of use and your done. The email verification is delayed so that you can start directly

Comment: I have not. You don't have to use a password_confirm, you can just use a standard password field. Similarly the email verification is optional in Drupal, the registration form completely configurable, and the entire submission process editable. You need to decide what you want, _then_ start looking into how you might do it. At the moment it sounds like you're soliciting for ideas and opinions - that's not what Q+A is for, Drupal Answers is here for when you get stuck actually implementing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan to allow users to login immediately and assign them a "not verified" role. Once they use the verification link they will become authenticated users.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Logintoboggan module](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan), it help you change the registration steps and flow.

Some of this module features :

> The LoginToboggan module offers several modifications of the Drupal
>   login system in an external module by offering the following features
>   and usability improvements:
>
> - Allow users to login using either their username OR their e-mail address.
> - Allow users to login immediately.
> - Provide a login form on Access Denied pages for non-logged-in (anonymous) users.
> - The module provides two login block options: One uses JavaScript to display the form within the block immediately upon clicking "log
>     in". The other brings the user to a separate page, but returns the
>     user to their original page upon login.
> - Customize the registration form with two e-mail fields to ensure accuracy.
> - Optionally redirect the user to a specific page when using the 'immediate login' feature.
> - Optionally redirect the user to a specific page upon validation of their e-mail address.
> - Optionally display a user message indicating a successful login.
> - Optionally combine both the login and registration form on one page.
>
>   - Optionally have unvalidated users purged from the system at a pre-defined interval (please read the CAVEATS section of INSTALL.txt
>       for important information on configuring this feature!).
> - Integrates with Rules module to do various tasks when a user validates via email validation process (see
>     http://drupal.org/node/880904 for an example)

Comment: @seb you're welcome,we are here to help each others ;